# Durable Id assignment in URL not working in lightning

Tags: url, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

**Problem Statement:**  To auto-populate the lookup field I use durable Id assignment with name. For e.g.  `https://sales--dev.my.salesforce.com/m2p/e?CF00N0l0000051XXX=Contract-00000XXX&inline=1`

Notice this -> `CF00N0l0000051XXX=Contract-00000XXX` ~ `durableId=recordName` In url.

Now, when the user clicks the `New` button to create a record on the VF page above URL is loaded in classic and populates the Name in lookup like this

[image]

**Trying to solve:**  In lightning, URL is getting overridden by this URL
`https://sales--dev.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/objectName/new?count=2` Is there a way to achieve the same URL in lightning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need it to be an URL hack? Can'y your thing be a quick action? The url prepopulation would be more reliable there and work everywhere.

URL hacking in lightning is bit simpler, you use field API names instead of IDs. These are decent tutorial: https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-for-lightning-tutorial/, https://sfdcdevelopers.com/2020/02/26/url-trick-in-salesforce-lightning/

So, how do you know where you are, in Classic or LEX. Which URL to use? Have a look at `UiThemeDisplayed` variable, available [in Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm) and in [Apex's `UserInfo` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm).

```
IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' || $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4t' || $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4u', 
    'link for lightning',
    'link for classic'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was about to answer my question. got know about URL Hacking. Thanks for your answer. I will put my detailed answer soon.

Comment: Used this userInfo.UiThemeDisplayed() but for some users, it is returning classic still the user is in lighting?

Comment: Sounds like bug. Search around a bit, maybe even raise ticket with Salesforce? Alternative method would be to maybe check if ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl() contains "lightning"? Does your VF page have `<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true"`?

Answer (score 0):

**Working approach:**

Created a controller for VF page:

```
global PageReference newParty() {
  PageReference pageRef;
  pageRef = new PageReference('/lightning/o/Party/new?defaultFieldValues=Contract='+contractID);
return pageRef
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this with a button / URL hack in lightning with the Spring '20 release. The URL can use "defaultFieldValues="
https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-for-lightning-tutorial/